# How do I install CoreAudio on newer versions of macOS?

Tags: macos, core-audio

I need to install the CoreAudio driver for my project. I opened Apple website, opened [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreaudio/building_an_audio_server_plug-in_and_driver_extension?language=objc) page and downloaded the archive. Then, when I tried to install it according to the instructions on this page, I got this error:

```
** INSTALL FAILED **

2023-07-29 15:14:13.237 xcodebuild[13012:113976] DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState: DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState_Disabled set via user default (DVTEnableCoreDevice=disabled)
Command line invocation:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -project SimpleAudio.xcodeproj -scheme SimpleAudioPlugIn DSTROOT=/tmp/SimpleAudio/dstroot SYMROOT=/tmp/SimpleAudio/symroot OBJROOT=/tmp/SimpleAudio/objroot install

User defaults from command line:
    IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES

Build settings from command line:
    DSTROOT = /tmp/SimpleAudio/dstroot
    OBJROOT = /tmp/SimpleAudio/objroot
    SYMROOT = /tmp/SimpleAudio/symroot

--- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
{ platform:macOS, arch:arm64, id:00008103-001D443A1AD0801E }
{ platform:macOS, arch:x86_64, id:00008103-001D443A1AD0801E }
{ platform:macOS, name:Any Mac }
Prepare packages

Computing target dependency graph and provisioning inputs

Create build description

note: Building targets in dependency order
/Users/admin/Downloads/BuildingAnAudioServerPlugInAndDriverExtension/SimpleAudio.xcodeproj: error: Signing for "SimpleAudioPlugIn" requires a development team. Select a development team in the Signing & Capabilities editor. (in target 'SimpleAudioPlugIn' from project 'SimpleAudio')
** INSTALL FAILED **

sudo: darwinup: command not found
```

If I understand correctly, the error is that darwinup is missing, it was cut from the system and it's kind of impossible to install. What are the options to install CoreAudio?

My MacOS version: Ventura 13.5